# For each loop add 1 in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to return a list of results from MySQL using PHP.

The basic query is simple and the output is multiple columns. I want to add a number so the array looks like this:

1. Club 1
2. Club 2

I have tried the below but it keeps breaking the script:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        for($i=1; $i++){
            $club = $row['club_name'];
            echo '<p>' . $i . $club . '</p>';
        }           
    }
}
```

I have then tried placing the for statement outside the while and inside it, changed it to foreach and used the format ($i=1; $i<100; $i++){} and it still doesn't work.

Sorry if this is an obvious one I've tried numerous different ways and it just isn't working for me.

Comment: Your `for` is invalid. It should have three parts. As written, it'll run forever. [edit] Whoops, that'd be if it was `$i = 1; ; $i++`. It'll be a parse error.

Comment: @ceejayoz or not have the `for` at all.

Comment: `for($i=1; $i++)` is not valid PHP. Read about the [`for` control structure](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php).

Comment: OK sorry I'll edit the question now

Comment: @ceejayoz as it is written it doesn't run forever. The script doesn't even start because it doesn't compile. Check it here: https://3v4l.org/r3Yv1

Comment: @axiac Yeah, I was thinking of the `for ($i=1; ; $i++) {` syntax in the docs.

Comment: Out of interest why am I being so heavily downvoted when I have genuinely tried my best on this? I'm learning and asked for help. Thanks for pushing me towards a ban...

Comment: @Rockhopper I personally downvote any question that says "it doesn't work" without elaborating on what that means - error messages, actual behavior, etc. The code you've shared should generate a very blatant parse error you should've shared with us.

Comment: Appreciate that but this sometimes seems a very tough site for newbies. Would be nice if someone could see my low reputation and think, perhaps he needs it explaining. Really appreciate the help in any case but still doesn't make someone feel welcome for a minor mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try creating a counter variable (`$i`) and incrementing it on every iteration of the while loop (`$i++`), like this:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $i = 1;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $club = $row['club_name'];
        echo '<p>' . $i . $club . '</p>';
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Then, to change the format to match `1. Club Name`, change

```
echo '<p>' . $i . $club . '</p>';
```

to

```
echo "<p>$i. $club</p>";
```

But, I'd personally recommend to use an [`<ol>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ol.asp) instead and skip setting the counter altogether like this:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo "<ol>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $club = $row['club_name'];
        echo "<li>$club</li>";
    }
    echo "</ol>";
}
```